# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple - no sum()

Tags: python

I got this error TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple for the part of my code which is in bold. How can I do a sum without the function sum() ?

````
q_0_seq = ()
q_3_seq = ()
q_3 = 0
q_0 = (input('Voulez-vous ajouter un jour ? (o/n)'))

if q_0 == "o":
    q_0 = True
    q_0_seq = q_0_seq + (q_0,)
else:
    q_0 = False

while q_0 == True:
  
q_3 = int(input("Combien de minutes d'activité physique avez-vous effectué?"))
q_3_seq = q_3_seq + (q_3,)
q_0 = (input('Voulez-vous ajouter un jour ? (o/n)'))

q_3_sum = 0
for q_3 in q_3_seq:
    **q_3_sum = q_3_seq + q_3**

q_3_mean = q_3_sum / len(q_3_seq)
if q_3_mean < 30:
    print("Vous ne faites pas suffisamment de sport! Visez 30 minutes par jour en moyenne.")```
````

Comment: I'd suggest using lists instead of tuples so you can simply `append` in place.  Building up a tuple by concatenation is doable but as this question demonstrates it's a bit awkward.

Answer (score 2):

Make that:

```
q_3_sum = q_3_sum + q_3
```